# Не распаковывает архив

Tags: python, парсер, ос, zip

Парсер должен после скачивания должен распаковать архив в папку, если таковой нет - создает, в нужной директории. Но проходит все проверки и ничего не происходит, архив остается в загрузках. Папка есть, но новую не создает и ничего не качает. Прогаю криво, за это прошу прощения.

```
    @staticmethod
    def __is_tome_name(chapter: WebElement) -> bool:
        td_count = chapter.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
        return len(td_count) == 1

    @staticmethod
    def __is_chapter_disabled(chapter: WebElement) -> bool:
        try:
            chapter.find_elements(
                By.TAG_NAME, 'td'
            )[5].find_element(
                By.TAG_NAME, 'span'
            ).get_attribute('class')
        except Exception:  # noqa
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def __check_chapters(self, chapters: Iterable[WebElement]) -> bool:
        can_download_any = False
        for chapter in chapters:
            if not self.__is_tome_name(chapter) and not self.__is_chapter_disabled(chapter):
                can_download_any = True
                chapter.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="download_chapter[]"]').click()

        return can_download_any

    def __click_download_btn(self):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.daun_lexa_selector).click()
        except:
            self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.dowload_selector_v2).click()

    def __download_chapters(self, title_name: str) -> None:
        self.__click_download_btn()
        sleep(1)
        for file in os.listdir(self.config['download_to_path']):
            if file.endswith('zip'):
                file_pats = os.path.join(self.config['download_to_path'], file)
                print('123',file_pats)
                out_path = os.path.join(self.config["unpack_to_path"], title_name)
                print('213')
                with ZipFile(file_pats, 'r') as zfile:
                    print('321')
                    zfile.extractall(out_path)
                os.remove(file_pats)
                print('removed')

    def __parse_page(self, title_name: str):
        chapter_table = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.chapter_table_selector)
        chapters = chapter_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

        can_download_any = self.__check_chapters(chapters)
        self.__download_chapters(title_name) if can_download_any else None


    def __parse_link(self, link: str):
        self.driver.get(link)

        box = Select(self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.selector_box))
        box.select_by_visible_text('10')

        title_name = self.driver.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            self.name_selector,
        ).text.split('/')[1]

        for symbol in self.__ban_symbols:
            title_name.replace(symbol, '')

        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.selector_btn).click()

        sleep(1)

        last_page = self.driver.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            self.end_chapter_selector,
        ).get_attribute('href').split('=')[1]

        for page in range(0, int(last_page)):
            try:
                self.__parse_page(title_name)
            except:  # noqa
                self.driver.get(f'{link}?Chapter_page={page + 1}')
            print(f'Ошибка при парсинге {link}?Chapter_page={page}')
            sleep(0.5)
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: а точно смотришь в папке, которая в ``out_path``? И точно загружаются в папку ``file_pats``?

Comment: @Эникейщик До определенного проекта все хорошо работало, но почему-то с определенными архивами или проектами происходит то что описал выше. Сейчас перепроверил конфиг, проверил, вроде да. 

```"download_to_path" = "C:\\Users\\alex1\\Downloads" ```
```"unpack_to_path" = "C:\\Users\\alex1\\Downloads\\book" ``` 
Пробовал несколько вариантов расположения папок, 0 эмоций.

Comment: Для меня ваш код работает правильно. Значит, ошибка будет в части, которую вы в ваш вопрос не включили. — Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать *минимальный код* для воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. . См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarianD Добрый вечер, вот так?